# Sequelize search API not working as desired expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to search all columns and display the search result.

I am new to sequelize so used this code to do so, However here it is checking for full matches

I want to show details for partial matches also

How do i acheive this ?

```
router.post("/search-employees", async (req, res) => {
  const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
  try {
    const resp = await employee.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          { name: searchTerm },
          { age: searchTerm },
          { country: searchTerm },
          { position: searchTerm },
          { wage: searchTerm },
        ],
      },
    });
    res.status(200).send(resp);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like operation e.g ([OP.LIKE], [OP.ILIKE]). Found Updated query below.

```
router.post("/search-employees", async (req, res) => {
const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
try {
 const resp = await employee.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { name: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchTerm + '%'} },
      { age: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchTerm + '%'} }, 
      { country: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchTerm + '%'} }, 
      { position: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchTerm + '%'} },
      { wage: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchTerm + '%'} }  
    ],
  },
});
res.status(200).send(resp);
} catch (e) {
res.status(400).send(e);
}
});
```